# Magnetic levitation project

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields

For the past four years, I have been working on a project that will allow permanent magnets to levitate stably above a magnetic surface. So far I have tested my first theory which was to see if locking multiple magnets to a single rotational axis would prevent magnets from flipping, it did. My next test is where I am at a loss, so I have a couple of questions, please bear in mind that I am working with logic rather than knowledge so I suspect a lot of eye rolling may take place :).

So the main two things I noticed during Test 1 was that the magnets, although happy to sit on the magnetic field, did want to slide off, I know this is due to the curve of the field, my questions are these, 1] is a magnetic field local or global to the magnets orientation ? If, as I suspect, it's local to the magnet, then could shape of the field be shaped by using a flexible magnetic sheet? My logic says it should be possible for a magnetic field to maintain its original shape the field would have to be able to increase and decrease its strength in accordance with surface deformation.

The reason I ask is I need to flatten the magnetic field of the surface, which I'm thinking, if I give the surface a slight concave bend, theoretically the field should adhere to that shape as well, giving a flatter top surface.

Comment: Think of the fields of a [bar magnet & a horseshoe magnet](http://avstop.com/ac/apgeneral/image8r8.jpg).

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you're attempting with Quantum Locking. Have you looked into the application?

Comment: Webfrogs, i have looked at quantum locking, but that becomes to costly and too restrictive, needing liquid nitrogen all the time becomes prohibitive on many levels, i believe though i am possibly one step away from finalizing this experiment, not entirely sure how much knowledge you have in the field of magnetics but maybe you can answer this question, if a magnet was flexible, would the magnetic field reshape itself as the magnet was flexed or would it keep its elliptical shape?.